# jQuery - Call click event on dinamiclly created button in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table which i populate with content via ajax and php.
I dinamiclly generate table rows and last column is row need to contain link/button where i need to call action for deliting that item (eg.Product) from table row.

I dont have idea how to call that specific `ID`  becouse all is happening in loop `each`. Only in loop i have information about product id but in loop to call `click()` event not work and is so dumb for me. I think there is better solution to do that.

**Check my code:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/admin/dokument/5/edit?ajax',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                 
                response = $.parseJSON(response);

                $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                    i++;
                    var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                        $('<td>').text(i),
                        $('<td>').text(item.id),
                        $('<td>').text(item.name),
                        $('<td>').text(item.qty),
                        $('<td>').text(item.jm),
                        $('<td>').text(item.price),
                        $('<td>').text(item.discount),
                        $('<td>').text(item.pdv),
                        $('<td>').text(item.total),

                        <!-- this is for delete -->

                        $('<td class="text-center">').html('<button type="button" id="product_'+item.id+'" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>'),

                        
                        // This not work inside loop
                        $("#product_"+item.id).click(function(e) {
                            alert(item.id);
                        }),

                    ).appendTo('#document_items_table > tbody');
                 });

             },
              complete: function(){
                $loading.hide();
              }
```

Do you have any idea how to execute this for specific product? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` attributes generated at runtime are an anti-pattern as they make the code more complex for no benefit.

To do what you require use a common class on all the buttons you generate, then you can use a delegated event handler along with DOM traversal methods to relate content to the button which was clicked.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/admin/dokument/5/edit?ajax',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    response = $.parseJSON(response);    

    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
      var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(++i),
        $('<td>').text(item.id),
        $('<td>').text(item.name),
        $('<td>').text(item.qty),
        $('<td>').text(item.jm),
        $('<td>').text(item.price),
        $('<td>').text(item.discount),
        $('<td>').text(item.pdv),
        $('<td>').text(item.total),
        $('<td class="text-center">').html(`<button type="button" data-id="${item.id}" class="btn btn-sm btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>`)
      ).appendTo('#document_items_table > tbody');
    });
  },
  complete: function() {
    $loading.hide();
  }
})

$('#document_items_table > tbody').on('click', '.btn-delete', function() {
  let id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

It's also worth noting that building HTML in JS as you are is not ideal. A better approach would be to use a `<template />` element in your HTML and then clone that for each row. You can then also build a single HTML string which gets appended once. This will be faster than building 11 jQuery objects and appending to the DOM in every iteration of your loop.

Comment: Thanks alot my friend. I will try to improve my code for your sugestion!